# [SOLVED]The right syntax for handling an UPDATE trigger and logging what happened per column?

Tags: mysql, trigger

**SOLVED**
The users table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastlogin` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `joined` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `loggedin` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sessionkey` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `verifycode` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `verified` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `banned` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `locked` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ip_address` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `failedattempts` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `unlocktime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The user_records table:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_records` (
  `id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` int(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `action` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oldentry` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `newentry` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

My trigger code for the users table to insert on user_records table:

```
    USE `gknet`;
   DELIMITER $$
   CREATE TRIGGER `after_update_user` AFTER UPDATE ON `users` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.loggedin != OLD.loggedin OR NEW.sessionkey != OLD.sessionkey THEN
        IF NEW.loggedin = '1' THEN
            INSERT INTO users (NEW.lastlogin)
            VALUES (NOW());
            INSERT INTO user_records (userid, action, oldentry, newentry, timestamp)
            VALUES (NEW.ID,'LOGGED_IN',OLD.sessionkey,NEW.sessionkey,NOW());
        ELSE IF NEW.loggedin = '0' THEN
            INSERT INTO user_records (userid, action, oldentry, newentry, timestamp)
            VALUES (NEW.ID,'LOGGED_OUT',OLD.sessionkey,NEW.sessionkey,NOW());
        END IF;
    END IF;

    IF NEW.locked != OLD.locked OR NEW.unlocktime != OLD.unlocktime THEN
        IF NEW.locked = '1' THEN
            INSERT INTO user_records (userid, action, oldentry, newentry, timestamp)
            VALUES (NEW.ID,'LOCKED',OLD.unlocktime,NEW.unlocktime,NOW());
        ELSE IF NEW.locked = '0' THEN
            INSERT INTO user_records (userid, action, oldentry, newentry, timestamp)
            VALUES (NEW.ID,'UNLOCKED',OLD.unlocktime,NEW.unlocktime,NOW());
        END IF;
    END IF;

    IF NEW.ip_address != OLD.ip_address THEN
        INSERT INTO user_records (userid, action, oldentry, newentry, timestamp)
        VALUES (NEW.ID,'IP_CHANGE',OLD.ip_address,NEW.ip_address,NOW());
    END IF;

    IF NEW.verified != OLD.verified THEN
        IF NEW.verified = '1' THEN
            INSERT INTO user_records (userid, action, timestamp)
            VALUES (NEW.ID,'VERIFIED',NOW());
        ELSE IF NEW.verified = '0' THEN
            INSERT INTO user_records (userid, action, timestamp)
            VALUES (NEW.ID,'UNVERIFIED',NOW());
        END IF;
    END IF;
END
$$
```

MySQL keeps saying there is an error near line 38 (second END IF from the bottom). If I remove that whole IF statement, it will give the error again for the one above it. How do I fix this? What is the correct syntax?

**Edit:** Replacing `ELSE` IF with `ELSEIF` like so doesn't help:

```
USE `gknet`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `after_update_user` AFTER UPDATE ON `users` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF NEW.loggedin != OLD.loggedin OR NEW.sessionkey != OLD.sessionkey THEN
    IF NEW.loggedin = '1' THEN
        INSERT INTO users (NEW.lastlogin)
        VALUES (NOW());
        INSERT INTO user_records (userid, action, oldentry, newentry,  timestamp)
        VALUES (NEW.ID,'LOGGED_IN',OLD.sessionkey,NEW.sessionkey,NOW());
    ELSEIF NEW.loggedin = '0' THEN
        INSERT INTO user_records (userid, action, oldentry, newentry, timestamp)
        VALUES (NEW.ID,'LOGGED_OUT',OLD.sessionkey,NEW.sessionkey,NOW());
    END IF;
END IF;

IF NEW.locked != OLD.locked OR NEW.unlocktime != OLD.unlocktime THEN
    IF NEW.locked = '1' THEN
        INSERT INTO user_records (userid, action, oldentry, newentry, timestamp)
        VALUES (NEW.ID,'LOCKED',OLD.unlocktime,NEW.unlocktime,NOW());
    ELSEIF NEW.locked = '0' THEN
        INSERT INTO user_records (userid, action, oldentry, newentry, timestamp)
        VALUES (NEW.ID,'UNLOCKED',OLD.unlocktime,NEW.unlocktime,NOW());
    END IF;
END IF;

IF NEW.ip_address != OLD.ip_address THEN
    INSERT INTO user_records (userid, action, oldentry, newentry, timestamp)
    VALUES (NEW.ID,'IP_CHANGE',OLD.ip_address,NEW.ip_address,NOW());
END IF;

IF NEW.verified != OLD.verified THEN
    IF NEW.verified = '1' THEN
        INSERT INTO user_records (userid, action, timestamp)
        VALUES (NEW.ID,'VERIFIED',NOW());
    ELSEIF NEW.verified = '0' THEN
        INSERT INTO user_records (userid, action, timestamp)
        VALUES (NEW.ID,'UNVERIFIED',NOW());
    END IF;
END IF;
END;
$$
```

**Edit:** Just removed the line INSERTing into the users table. Same error

```
USE `gknet`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `after_update_user` AFTER UPDATE ON `users` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF NEW.loggedin != OLD.loggedin OR NEW.sessionkey != OLD.sessionkey THEN
    IF NEW.loggedin = '1' THEN
        INSERT INTO user_records (userid, action, oldentry, newentry,  timestamp)
        VALUES (NEW.ID,'LOGGED_IN',OLD.sessionkey,NEW.sessionkey,NOW());
    ELSEIF NEW.loggedin = '0' THEN
        INSERT INTO user_records (userid, action, oldentry, newentry, timestamp)
        VALUES (NEW.ID,'LOGGED_OUT',OLD.sessionkey,NEW.sessionkey,NOW());
    END IF;
END IF;

IF NEW.locked != OLD.locked OR NEW.unlocktime != OLD.unlocktime THEN
    IF NEW.locked = '1' THEN
        INSERT INTO user_records (userid, action, oldentry, newentry, timestamp)
        VALUES (NEW.ID,'LOCKED',OLD.unlocktime,NEW.unlocktime,NOW());
    ELSEIF NEW.locked = '0' THEN
        INSERT INTO user_records (userid, action, oldentry, newentry, timestamp)
        VALUES (NEW.ID,'UNLOCKED',OLD.unlocktime,NEW.unlocktime,NOW());
    END IF;
END IF;

IF NEW.ip_address != OLD.ip_address THEN
    INSERT INTO user_records (userid, action, oldentry, newentry, timestamp)
    VALUES (NEW.ID,'IP_CHANGE',OLD.ip_address,NEW.ip_address,NOW());
END IF;

IF NEW.verified != OLD.verified THEN
    IF NEW.verified = '1' THEN
        INSERT INTO user_records (userid, action, timestamp)
        VALUES (NEW.ID,'VERIFIED',NOW());
    ELSEIF NEW.verified = '0' THEN
        INSERT INTO user_records (userid, action, timestamp)
        VALUES (NEW.ID,'UNVERIFIED',NOW());
    END IF;
END IF;
END;
$$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I indented everything and quickly noticed that the last `END` must have `$$` after it, not the `;`

```
USE `gknet`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `after_update_user` AFTER UPDATE ON `users` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.loggedin != OLD.loggedin OR NEW.sessionkey != OLD.sessionkey THEN
        IF NEW.loggedin = '1' THEN
            INSERT INTO user_records (userid, action, oldentry, newentry,  timestamp)
            VALUES (NEW.ID,'LOGGED_IN',OLD.sessionkey,NEW.sessionkey,NOW());
        ELSEIF NEW.loggedin = '0' THEN
            INSERT INTO user_records (userid, action, oldentry, newentry, timestamp)
            VALUES (NEW.ID,'LOGGED_OUT',OLD.sessionkey,NEW.sessionkey,NOW());
        END IF;
    END IF;
    IF NEW.locked != OLD.locked OR NEW.unlocktime != OLD.unlocktime THEN
        IF NEW.locked = '1' THEN
            INSERT INTO user_records (userid, action, oldentry, newentry, timestamp)
            VALUES (NEW.ID,'LOCKED',OLD.unlocktime,NEW.unlocktime,NOW());
        ELSEIF NEW.locked = '0' THEN
            INSERT INTO user_records (userid, action, oldentry, newentry, timestamp)
            VALUES (NEW.ID,'UNLOCKED',OLD.unlocktime,NEW.unlocktime,NOW());
        END IF;
    END IF;
    IF NEW.ip_address != OLD.ip_address THEN
        INSERT INTO user_records (userid, action, oldentry, newentry, timestamp)
        VALUES (NEW.ID,'IP_CHANGE',OLD.ip_address,NEW.ip_address,NOW());
    END IF;
    IF NEW.verified != OLD.verified THEN
        IF NEW.verified = '1' THEN
            INSERT INTO user_records (userid, action, timestamp)
            VALUES (NEW.ID,'VERIFIED',NOW());
        ELSEIF NEW.verified = '0' THEN
            INSERT INTO user_records (userid, action, timestamp)
            VALUES (NEW.ID,'UNVERIFIED',NOW());
        END IF;
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

I also appended

```
DELIMITER ;
```

to get the `;` back as the normal command delimiter.

Comment: That worked, thanks! Sorry, I can't upvote! Rep is too low